# Python Selenium LinkedIn company webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use webscraping (via Python and Selenium) to create a worksheet with companies of interest to my boss. Most of it is working, I just can't seem to get hold of the "Next Page" button. Relative and absolute XPaths, CSS selectors, nothing seems to work, since every time you generate/switch pages they're diferent. (The relative XPath usually is **'//*[@id="ember{SOME RANDOM NUMBER}"]'**) What could I do? There are other buttons with the same relative XPath structure in the page. [image: Here's the damn button I'm trying to click.]

Comment: Can we see the html for the next button as text not an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Next page` button has the same XPath for all the pages.
It is `//button[@aria-label="Next"]`
You should locate this element according to the `aria-label` attribute, not the `id` attribute value.

Comment: Selenium said it wasn't able to locate any element with that XPath

Comment: have you scrolled to the page down before locating that element?

Comment: can you share the HML of next page button element in your language?

Comment: that indeed was the problem, thanks! But after clicking the element, I got the following error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)`

Comment: Ok, please share ALL the relevant code and we will try to help with it. Please open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class_name function to locate 'Next' element

```
next_button = wd.find_element_by_class_name('artdeco-pagination__button next').click()
```